# Do I need to declare arrays as static local variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, static, allocation

Let's say that I have a function that I call a lot which has an array in it:

```
char foo[LENGTH];
```

Depending upon the value of `LENGTH` this may be expensive to allocate every time the function is called. I have seen:

```
static char foo[LENGTH];
```

So that it is only allocated once and that array is always used: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables

Is that best practice for arrays?

**EDIT:**

I've seen several responses that static locals are not best. But what about initialization cost? What if I'd called:

```
char foo[LENGTH] = "lorem ipsum";
```

Isn't that going to have to be copied every time I call the function?

Comment: Downvoting for moving goal post.

Comment: @Bathsheba my Latin is week. Could you please translate?

Comment: @JonathanMee Regarding your edit, if you want to modify foo in your function you would have to manually reset it anyway otherwise it might still have the modified content of the previous iteration. I assume this is undesirable because if it was desirable you would have had to use static from the start and there would be no question. If you don't want to modify foo you can just use const char * foo instead. Either case, static is of no help.

Comment: Note that your edit invalidated 4 answers already provided that answered the original question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes :( I messaged them. My apologies.

Comment: No apology is necessary. Just accept one of the answers for this question, revert your changes and ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

As LENGTH is supposed to be a compile time constant (C++, no C99 VLA), `foo` is just going to use space on the stack. Very fast.

Comment: So sorry, I've moved the goal posts a little... but what about initialization? Will that change our preference?

Comment: You should ask the question for this specific case, because it's going to be a totally different answer (see https://godbolt.org/z/Kaia8H).

Answer (score 1):

First off, time to allocate automatic array of char is not dependent on it's size, and on any sane implementation is a constant time complexity of incrementing stack pointer, which is superfast. Please note, this would be the same even for VLA (which are not valid in C++), only that increment would be a run-time operand. Also please note, the answer would be different if your array would be initialized.

So it is really unclear what performance drawback you are referring to.

On the other hand, if you make the said array `static`, you would incur no penalty whatsoever in the provided example - since char is not initialized, there will be no normal synchronization which prevents static variables from getting doubly initialized. However, your function will (likely) become thread-unsafe.

Bottom line: premature optimization is the root of evil.

Comment: Yeah, I did move the goal posts after asking :( I was actually wondering *with* initialization, does it make sense to use a static local variable?

Comment: No apology is necessary. Just accept one of the answers for this question, revert your changes and ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

"Allocating" an object of primitive data type and with automatic storage duration is usually not a big deal. The question is more: Do you want that the contents of `foo` to survive the execution of the function or not?

Consider, for example, following function:

```
char* bar() {
   char foo[LENGTH];
   strcpy(foo, "Hello!");
   return foo;  // returning a pointer to a local variable; undefined behaviour if someone will use it.
}
```

In this case, `foo` will go out of scope and will not be (legally) accessible when `bar` has finished.

Everything is OK, however, if you write

```
char* bar() {
   static char foo[LENGTH];
   strcpy(foo, "Hello!");
   return foo;  // foo has static storage duration and will be destroyed at the end of your program (not at the end of bar())
}
```

An issue with large variables with automatic storage duration might arise, if they get so large that they will exceed a (limited) stack size, or if you call the function recursively. To overcome this issue, however, you'd need to use dynamic memory allocation instead (i.e. new/delete).

Comment: I don't think the size is a concern. I believe the compiler will handle that for me already. If this is too big it will handle putting it on the heap.

Comment: No, the compiler will not do that. It will be "on the stack", and you will get problems (likely without any warning) when `LENGTH` is getting to large.

Comment: @JonathanMee, no, it will not. If array grows above the allowed stack size, you will have... guess what... **STACK OVERFLOW**!

Comment: However, Stephan is wrong. `static char foo[LENGTH];` is never going to be allocated on stack. If anything, the answer should be in reverse - large automatic variables pose an risk of stack overflow, while statics do not.

Comment: @SergeyA: right; "local variable"  is the wrong term; corrected it to "automatic storage duration".